# Sync DB Tables not being created when creating a User Profile Service Application?

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync, sync

Been having difficult getting the User profile synchronization service started. Deleted and recreated the service multiple times. Now I notice after creating the UPS application the profile db, social db and sync db's are created but noticed that the sync db has no tables. Anyone have any idea why? I suspect it is part of a bigger issue that is preventing the synchronization service to start.

Comment: did you get this answered?

Comment: What is logged in the Windows Application event log at the time you try to start the User Profile Service application?

Answer (score 0):

Tables will be created in Sync DB when [User Profile Synchronization Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization#phase-1-start-the-user-profile-synchronization-service) is started for the 1st time.